# I am unable to understand what went wrong in my movement code for the nokia classic snake game remake. Please help me

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

Please help me.
As we know in the snake game, if we are currently moving to the right: we cannot move to the left, we have to move either up or down or persist with moving right. And so on respectively for the other directions. So I came up with the following code:

```
extends Area2D

export var SPEED=100
var input_vector= Vector2.ZERO
var canMove = {'left':false, 'right':false, 'up':false, 'down':false}
var moving = {'left':false, 'right':false, 'up':false, 'down':false}


func _physics_process(delta):
    
    position += input_vector*SPEED*delta
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right"):
        input_vector.x=1
        input_vector.y=0
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_left"):
        input_vector.x=-1
        input_vector.y=0
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
        input_vector.x=0
        input_vector.y=-1
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_down"):
        input_vector.x=0
        input_vector.y=1

    
    if input_vector.x<0:
        moving['left']=true
    if input_vector.x>0:
        moving['right']=true

    if input_vector.y<0:
        moving['up']=true
    if input_vector.y>0:
        moving['down']=true


    if moving['left']==true:
        canMove['right']=false
        canMove['up']=true
        canMove['down']=true
    if moving['right']==true:
        canMove['left']=false
        canMove['up']=true
        canMove['down']=true
    if moving['up']==true:
        canMove['right']=true
        canMove['left']=true
        canMove['down']=false
    if moving['down']==true:
        canMove['right']=true
        canMove['left']=true
        canMove['up']=false


    if canMove['left']==false:
        input_vector.x= abs(input_vector.x)
    if canMove['right']==false:
        input_vector.x= -abs(input_vector.x)

    if canMove['up']==false:
        input_vector.y= abs(input_vector.y)
    if canMove['down']==false:
        input_vector.y= -abs(input_vector.y)
```

Answer (score 2):

After `position += input_vector*SPEED*delta`. The first block writes `input_vector` based on `Input`.

The second block writes `moving` based on `input_vector`. Since we are writing `input_vector` based on `Input`, these blocks combined write `moving` based on `input_vector`.

The third block writes `canMove` based on `moving`. By the same logic as above, you are writing `canMove` based on `Input`. When are you checking `canMove`? last. This is not what you want. You want to check `canMove` first, before writing `input_vector` and `moving`.

In fact, you can combine the checks, for example:

```
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right") and canMove['right']:
```

---

I don't think this is a good way to represent `moving`. Instead, I'd suggest to use an [Enum](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#enums). That is:

```
enum Direction {UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, NONE}
var moving = Direction.NONE
```

You may also get rid of `canMove`. The rule is that you can't move to the direction opposite to where you are moving. Thus, you can check `moving` directly:

```
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right") and moving != Direction.LEFT:
        input_vector.x=1
        input_vector.y=0
        moving = Direction.RIGHT
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_left") and moving != Direction.RIGHT:
        input_vector.x=-1
        input_vector.y=0
        moving = Direction.LEFT
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up") and moving != Direction.DOWN:
        input_vector.x=0
        input_vector.y=-1
        moving = Direction.UP
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_down") and moving != Direction.UP:
        input_vector.x=0
        input_vector.y=1
        moving = Direction.DOWN
```

That block should be enough.

Comment: wow, amazing. so simple neat and yet so effective. I just tried out the solution and it works out like a charm. I learnt a lesson today thanks to Theraot!